# Android listview in API integration JSON parsing

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I had try to parse the json value to my listview. I am getting the error in logcat as json parsing error, Instead of the result appearing in listview,the entire json response is appearing in toast, Please help me to solve it. Thanks.

Here is my java code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView lv;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = " https://private-2a004-androidtest3.apiary-mock.com/employeesList";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> employeeList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new Getemployees().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class Getemployees extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray employees = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < employees.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = employees.getJSONObject(i);
                    String firstName = c.getString("firstName");
                    String lastName = c.getString("lastName");
                    String designation = c.getString("designation");
                    String city = c.getString("city");
                    HashMap<String, String> emp = new HashMap<>();
                    emp.put("firstName", firstName);
                    emp.put("lastName", lastName);
                    emp.put("designation",designation);
                    emp.put("city",city);
                    employeeList.add(emp);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, employeeList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"firstName","lastName","designation", "city"},new int[]{R.id.firstName,
                R.id.lastName,R.id.city,R.id.designation});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

}

HttpHandler.java

```
public class HttpHandler {
private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public HttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

My logcat:

```
02-17 15:45:03.667 24027-24149/com.example.simple E/MainActivity: Response from url: [
                                                                      {

                                                                          "employee": 
                                                                          [
                                                                            {
                                                                              "id": "1",
                                                                              "firstName": "Ram",
                                                                              "lastName": "Kumar",
                                                                              "address" : "1/20, Rich street",
                                                                              "city" : "Karur",
                                                                              "zipcode" : "636138",
                                                                              "gender" : "male",
                                                                              "dob" : "20-May-1995",
                                                                              "designation":"developer",
                                                                              "mobile" : "9988776655",
                                                                              "email" : "tom@gmail.com",
                                                                              "nationality" : "Indian",
                                                                              "language" : "English",
                                                                              "imageURL" : "https://dummyimage.com/500x500/d12ad1/fff.png&text=Ram",
                                                                              "skills": [
                                                                                {
                                                                                  "technical" : [ "C", "C++", "Java" ],
                                                                                  "extra_curricular" : ["chess", "cricket"]
                                                                                }]
                                                                            },
                                                                            {
                                                                              "id": "2",
                                                                              "firstName": "Kumari",
                                                                              "lastName": "Raja",
                                                                              "address" : "2/20, Rich street",
                                                                              "city" : "Coimbatore",
                                                                              "zipcode" : "636148",
                                                                              "gender" : "female",
                                                                              "dob" : "10-Jun-1995",
                                                                              "designation":"Tester",
                                                                              "mobile" : "8899667744",
                                                                              "email" : "maria@gmail.com",
                                                                              "nationality" : "Indian",
                                                                              "language" : "Tamil",
                                                                              "imageURL" : "https://dummyimage.com/500x500/52d929/fff.png&text=Kumari",
                                                                              "skills": [
                                                                                {
                                                                                  "technical" : [ "C", "C++", ".net" ],
                                                                                  "extra_curricular" : ["Tennis", "Carrom"]
                                                                                }]
                                                                            },
                                                                            {
                                                                              "id": "3",
                                                                              "firstName": "Raja",
                                                                              "lastName": "Ravi",
                                                                              "address" : "13/20, Rich street",
                                                                              "city" : "Salem",
                                                                              "zipcode" : "636138",
                                                                              "gender" : "male",
                                                                              "dob" : "22-Jan-1994",
                                                                              "designation":"Team Lead",
                                                                              "mobile" : "9876543210",
                                                                              "email" : "raja@gmail.com",
                                                                              "nationality" : "Indian",
                                                                              "language" : "English",
                                                                              "imageURL" : "https://dummyimage.com/500x500/bef0af/fff.png&text=Raja",
                                                                              "skills": [
                                                                                {
                                                                                  "technical" : [ "C", "C++", "Java" , "Android"],
                                                                                  "extra_curricular" : ["chess", "cricket"]
                                                                                }]
                                                                            },
                                                                            {
                                                                              "id": "4",
                                                                              "firstName": "Sheela",
                                                                              "lastName": "Ravi",
                                                                              "address" : "14/20, Rich street",
                                                                              "city" : "Madurai",
                                                                              "zipcode" : "636200",
                                                                              "gender" : "female",
                                                                              "dob" : "10-Feb-1985",
                                                                              "designation":"developer",
                                                                              "mobile" : "5566778899",
                                                                              "email" : "Sheela@gmail.com",
                                                                              "nationality" : "Indian",
                                                                              "language" : "Tamil",
                                                                              "imageURL" : "https://dummyimage.com/500x500/e6866e/fff.png&text=Sheela",
                                                                              "skills": [
                                                                                {
                                                                                  "technical" : [ "photoshop", "Ruby" ],
                                                                                  "extra_curricular" : ["Carrom", "Reading books"]
                                                                                }]
                                                                            },
                                                                            {
                                                                              "id": "5",
                                                                              "firstName": "Shankar",
                                                                              "lastName": "Kumar",
                                                                              "address" : "15/20, Rich street",
                                                                              "city" : "Madurai",
                                                                              "zipcode" : "636300",
                                                                              "gender" : "Male",
                                                                              "dob" : "10-Feb-1985",
                                                                              "designation":"Sr.Developer",
                                                                              "mobile" : "5566778899",
                                                                              "email" : "shankar@gmail.com",
                                                                              "nationality" : "Indian",
                                                                              "language" : "Tamil",
                                                                              "imageURL" : "https://dummyimage.com/500x500/8f3532/fff.png&text=Shankar",
                                                                              "skills": [
                                                                                {
                                                                                  "technical" : [ "C", "C++" ],
                                                                                  "extra_curricular" : ["chess", "Drawing"]
                                                                                }]
                                                                            },
                                                                            {
                                                                              "id": "6",
                                                                              "firstName": "Suren",
                                                                              "lastName": "Saker",
                                                                              "address" : "16/20, Rich street",
                                                                              "city" : "Salem",
                                                                              "zipcode" : "636400",
                                                                              "gender" : "Male",
                                                                              "dob" : "14-Jan-1985",
                                                                              "designat
02-17 15:45:03.676 24027-24149/com.example.simple E/MainActivity: Json parsing error: Value [{"employee":[{"id":"1","firstName":"Ram","lastName":"Kumar","address":"1\/20, Rich street","city":"Karur","zipcode":"636138","gender":"male","dob":"20-May-1995","designation":"developer","mobile":"9988776655","email":"tom@gmail.com","nationality":"Indian","language":"English","imageURL":"https:\/\/dummyimage.com\/500x500\/d12ad1\/fff.png&text=Ram","skills":[{"technical":["C","C++","Java"],"extra_curricular":["chess","cricket"]}]},{"id":"2","firstName":"Kumari","lastName":"Raja","address":"2\/20, Rich street","city":"Coimbatore","zipcode":"636148","gender":"female","dob":"10-Jun-1995","designation":"Tester","mobile":"8899667744","email":"maria@gmail.com","nationality":"Indian","language":"Tamil","imageURL":"https:\/\/dummyimage.com\/500x500\/52d929\/fff.png&text=Kumari","skills":[{"technical":["C","C++",".net"],"extra_curricular":["Tennis","Carrom"]}]},{"id":"3","firstName":"Raja","lastName":"Ravi","address":"13\/20, Rich street","city":"Salem","zipcode":"636138","gender":"male","dob":"22-Jan-1994","designation":"Team Lead","mobile":"9876543210","email":"raja@gmail.com","nationality":"Indian","language":"English","imageURL":"https:\/\/dummyimage.com\/500x500\/bef0af\/fff.png&text=Raja","skills":[{"technical":["C","C++","Java","Android"],"extra_curricular":["chess","cricket"]}]},{"id":"4","firstName":"Sheela","lastName":"Ravi","address":"14\/20, Rich street","city":"Madurai","zipcode":"636200","gender":"female","dob":"10-Feb-1985","designation":"developer","mobile":"5566778899","email":"Sheela@gmail.com","nationality":"Indian","language":"Tamil","imageURL":"https:\/\/dummyimage.com\/500x500\/e6866e\/fff.png&text=Sheela","skills":[{"technical":["photoshop","Ruby"],"extra_curricular":["Carrom","Reading books"]}]},{"id":"5","firstName":"Shankar","lastName":"Kumar","address":"15\/20, Rich street","city":"Madurai","zipcode":"636300","gender":"Male","dob":"10-Feb-1985","designation":"Sr.Developer","mobile":"5566778899","email":"shankar@gmail.com","nationality":"Indian","language":"Tamil","imageURL":"https:\/\/dummyimage.com\/500x500\/8f3532\/fff.png&text=Shankar","skills":[{"technical":["C","C++"],"extra_curricular":["chess","Drawing"]}]},{"id":"6","firstName":"Suren","lastName":"Saker","address":"16\/20, Rich street","city":"Salem","zipcode":"636400","gender":"Male","dob":"14-Jan-1985","designation":"Sr.Developer","mobile":"8899776655","email":"suren@gmail.com","nationality":"Indian","language":"English","imageURL":"http:\/\/indianapublicmedia.org\/arts\/files\/2012\/04\/sample-gates-9-940x626.jpg","skills":[{"technical":["Java","Android"],"extra_curricular":["Reading","Stamp collection"]}]},{"id":"7","firstName":"Rajesh","lastName":"Kumar","address":"17\/20, Rich street","city":"Karur","zipcode":"636800","gender":"Male","dob":"10-Feb-1985","designation":"Sr.Developer","mobile":"5566778899","email":"shankar@gmail.com","nationality":"Indian","language":"Tamil","imageURL":"http:\/\/images.fonearena.com\/blog\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/11\/Lenovo-p780-camera-sample-10.jpg","skills":[{"technical":["C","C++"],"extra_curricular":["chess","Drawing"]}]},{"id":"8","firstName":"Sham","lastName":"Kumar","address":"18\/20, Rich street","city":"Salem","zipcode":"636700","gender":"Male","dob":"08-Feb-1985","designation":"Sr.Developer","mobile":"7788996655","email":"sham@gmail.com","nationality":"Indian","language":"Tamil","imageURL":"https:\/\/taylorstaste.files.wordpress.com\/2014\/07\/screenshot-2014-07-03-10-25-41.png","skills":[{"technical":["C","C++"],"extra_curricular":["chess","Drawing"]}]},{"id":"9","firstName":"Jayakumar","lastName":"Ravi","address":"19\/20, Rich street","city":"Coimbatore","zipcode":"623300","gender":"Male","dob":"3-Mar-1986","designation":"Designer","mobile":"8879797979","email":"jaya@gmail.com","nationality":"Indian","language":"Tamil","imageURL":"http:\/\/images.fonearena.com\/blog\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/11\/google-nexus-5-macro-samples-1.jpg","skills":[{"technical":["Photoshop","Design tools"],"extra_curricular":["chess","Drawing"]}]},{
```

Comment: I hope your `contact` key is right, and you did not mean `employee` as we cannot see it in the log. If it is right: Try to `substring` `e.getMessage()` to remove the first 1000 (or 5000 or 10000) characters from your error so you can see where the error is. Otherwise, I'd recommend you run this request on your computer and check that the JSON is actually valid from some online service.

Comment: check your JSONObject "{" and JSONArray"[" sequence in code compare with your JSON and there is no "contacts" in your JSON JSONArray employees = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

Comment: Please Post your full JSON Response so i can help you

Comment: @ZakiPathan, here is my full JSON response:

Comment: Where? that is an logcat. I need full JSON response

Comment: Zaki, it works  for me when i tried as suggested by user2025187, thank you,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
        try {


            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonStr);

            JSONObject jsonObj =jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONArray employees = jsonObj.getJSONArray("employee");

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < employees.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = employees.getJSONObject(i);
                String firstName = c.getString("firstName");
                String lastName = c.getString("lastName");
                String designation = c.getString("designation");
                String city = c.getString("city");
                HashMap<String, String> emp = new HashMap<>();
                emp.put("firstName", firstName);
                emp.put("lastName", lastName);
                emp.put("designation",designation);
                emp.put("city",city);
                employeeList.add(emp);
            }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {

        }
```

Comment: @user2025187 Thank you very much, It really helped me

Comment: @ZakiPathan, yes Zaki, this worked for me, thank you very much

Comment: mark this as a correct answer so other get help from this

Comment: @ZakiPathan pls say me how can i pass the intent for each list row, Pls say me, Thanks

Comment: means? you are trying to open different activities from different list row?

Answer (score 0):

Json key does not match :

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonStr); // As your response is in json array format
JSONObject jsonObject =jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
// Getting JSON Array node
JSONArray employees = jsonObject.getJSONArray("employee");
```

Replace "contact" key with "employee" that will solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONArray  jsArray= new JSONArray(jsonStr) instesd of JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr) becouse your response is an JsonArray.